# error on pen1 Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net

when i run the code i'm getting error on pen1 saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
Dim pen1 As Pen
.
.
.
.
    Private Sub setDash()





    Select Case selectDash
        Case 1

            pen1.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash
        Case 2
            pen1.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dot
        Case 3
            pen1.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDot
        Case 4
            pen1.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.DashDotDot
        Case 5
            pen1.DashStyle = Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate `pen1` (you have just declared it). Sample code:

```
pen1 = New Pen(Brushes.Black)
```